# Python searching dictionary for matching key

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, linear-search

I am trying to iterate over a list of IP addresses and check whether each IP address exists as a dictionary key. My for-loop is returning the desired result for IP addresses that are found in the dictionary, however for IP addresses that are not found, the loop returns the IP address multiple times. Any ideas on a better way to do this.

```
subnet_dict = {'10.6.150.2/32': 'site-A', '10.2.150.2/32': 'site-B', '10.1.2.2/32': 'site-C'}

datafile = [['27/08/2015 18:23', '10/09/2015 12:20', '10.1.2.2', '15356903000'], ['3/09/2015 8:54', '3/09/2015 20:03', '10.1.2.3', '618609571'],
            ['27/08/2015 22:23', '10/09/2015 10:25', '10.1.2.4', '6067520'], ['27/08/2015 20:14', '10/09/2015 1:35', '10.99.88.6', '4044954']]

for row in datafile:
    dstip = row[2]

    for key, value in subnet_dict.iteritems():

        if dstip in key:
            print dstip, value + ' was FOUND in the dictionary'

        else:
            print dstip + ' was not found'
```

Output:

```
10.1.2.2 was not found
10.1.2.2 was not found
10.1.2.2 site-C was FOUND in the dictionary
10.1.2.3 was not found
10.1.2.3 was not found
10.1.2.3 was not found
10.1.2.4 was not found
10.1.2.4 was not found
10.1.2.4 was not found
10.99.88.6 was not found
10.99.88.6 was not found
10.99.88.6 was not found
```

Desired Output:

```
10.1.2.2 site-C was FOUND in the dictionary
10.1.2.3 was not found
10.1.2.4 was not found
10.99.88.6 was not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a very simple solution for you (notice the change in indentation):

```
for row in datafile:
    dstip = row[2]
    for key, value in subnet_dict.iteritems():
        if dstip in key:
            print dstip, value + ' was FOUND in the dictionary'
            break
    else:
        print dstip + ' was not found'
```

Comment: Thank you Nayuki, I knew the answer was going to be something simple. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know that it's always gonna be '/32' in the end of the strings of the subnet_dict you could do this:

```
for row in datafile:
    dstip = row[2]
    if dstip in [str.split('/')[0] for str in subnet_dict.keys()]:
        for k in subnet_dict:
            if k.split('/')[0] == dstip:
                print dstip + ' ' + subnet_dict[k] + ' was FOUND in the dictionary'
    else:
        print dstip + ' was not found'
```

if you do, then this'd be enough:

```
for row in datafile:
    dstip = row[2]
    if dstip + '/32' in subnet_dict:
        print dstip + ' ' + subnet_dict[dstip + '/32'] + ' was FOUND in the dictionary'
    else:
        print dstip + ' was not found'
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, appreciate it.